# Django subquery, annotate. Is there any way to join three tables for querying to find the aggregate sum of a field in django (query set api)?

Tags: python, django, orm, django-queryset

I am a complete beginner in django. I'm stuck with this problem and can't seem to find a solution to query it properly. (T-T)

```
django ver : 1.11 python ver : 2.7
```

Let's say we have 3 models:

```
class Coupon(models.Model):
    pass

class CouponApplication(models.Model):
    """
    Track application of a coupon.
    """
    coupon = models.ForeignKey(Coupon, related_name="applications",verbose_name=("Coupon"))
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, verbose_name=("Order")related_name='order_coupon_applications')

class Order(models.Model):

    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='user_order', verbose_name="Customer")
    order_date = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='Order Date and Time')
    shop = models.ForeignKey(Location, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)


class OrderItem(models.Model):
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, related_name='order_items')
    order_type = models.CharField('Type', choices=ORDER_ITEM_TYPE, default=INVENTORY)
    buy_get_discount = models.DecimalField(_('Buy & Get Discount'))
    sub_total = models.DecimalField(_('Sub Total'), max_digits=18, decimal_places=2)
```

Now for each coupon, I need to find the gross sales of the products, sold using it. I am finding it pretty hard to write a query for the same because I need to annotate the sum of subtotal of order item to each coupon object and I guess this requires joining coupon application, order item and order table .

So far I've written this much:

```
buy_gets_gross_sales = OrderItem.objects.filter(order_type=OrderItem.INVENTORY,
                                                        buy_get_discount__gt=0,
                                                        order_id__in=CouponApplication.objects.filter(coupon=OuterRef('pk'),
                                                            ).values('order')
                                                        ).values('order_type')
        gross_sales = buy_gets_gross_sales.annotate(gross=Sum('sub_total')).values('gross')
gross_Sales_report = Coupon.objects.annotate(
            total_gross_sales =Round(Coalesce(Subquery(gross_sales, output_field=models.DecimalField()), Value(0))) ,)
```

i know this wont work, but i need something of this sort. it is already throwing some errors saying the inner query need to be used in a subquery or something.I need the aggregate value to be annotated with the coupon objects.

I've added the raw sql query below too:

```
'(select coalesce(sum(sub_total),0) from order_orderitem'
            ' where order_type=%(order_type)s and buy_get_discount > %(discount)s'
            'and order_id in (select distinct(order_id) from coupon_couponapplication where coupon_id=t1.id '
            '{0}'
            'and date_created between %(start)s and %(end)s'  # comment this line to remove date filter
            ')) '
```

Here t1 is Coupon model.

Help, I am pretty sure it is possible to write django query for this one, but as I said I am not able to figure it out.

Please help me to find a solution, thanks in advance. <3